# how to lock a file stream without a mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I have been locking/unlocking files in multi-thread applications using something like

```
void Write_File(FILE* Input_File)
{
        flockfile(Input_File);
        Read_Stuff();
        funlock(Input_File);
}
```

I want to convert these routines to use streams. I cannot find similar commands to use with streams. Is there any way to lock the file streams without resorting to a mutex?

Comment: Are you simply trying to prevent some other thread in the same process from writing to the file, or "any process in the system"? Those are distinctly different matters, and the solution is very much different (or impossible, depending on the requirements and architecture of the system).

Comment: Are you really locking an input file before writing output?

Comment: @user315052 I actually wanted to read, I edited code to reflect this.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I want it to be safe from threads in the same process

Comment: Ok, then use a `mutex`, as Celada explains below. It will do the right thing, and work perfectly fine.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Celadas method works fine. However in my particular problem, I tried writing to different files for different threads and it was the best solution. The timing scales much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a C style stream around a C++ I/O stream style interface. The example below gives you an idea of how you might implement one using an `ostringstream`:

```
class lockedostream_impl : public std::ostringstream
{
    friend class lockedostream;
    struct buf_t : public std::stringbuf {
        FILE *f_;
        buf_t (FILE *f) : f_(f) { flockfile(f_); }
        ~buf_t () { funlockfile(f_); }
        int sync () {
            int r = (f_ ? -(fputs(str().c_str(), f_) == EOF) : 0);
            str(std::string());
            return r;
        }
    } buf_;
    std::ostream & os () { return *this; }
    lockedostream_impl (FILE *f) : buf_(f) { os().rdbuf(&buf_); }
};


class lockedostream {
    typedef std::ostream & (*manip_t) (std::ostream &);
    mutable lockedostream_impl impl_;
public:
    lockedostream (FILE *f) : impl_(f) {}
    template <typename T>
    const lockedostream & operator << (const T &t) const {
        impl_.os() << t;
        return *this;
    }
    const lockedostream & operator << (manip_t m) const {
        impl_.os() << m;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

You can change the locking primitive however you want, but I maintained your desire to use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()`. With this, you could write code that looked like this:

```
lockedostream(f)
    << some_stuff_to_be_written
    << some_other_stuff
    << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

`flockfile` basically *is* a mutex, at least in glibc, and probably on every other platform as well. So in a sense you are already "resorting to a mutex". If you change to just using a mutex instead nothing will change (as long as all code paths that operate on the file only do so while holding the mutex).

It is important to not confuse `flockfile` (which is a mutex that manages concurrent file operations between threads of a single process) with system-based advisory file locks, as you'd get with `flockf` or `fcntl(F_SETLK)`.